# Can I use LINQ to SQL inside .ASHX file?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If so, where do I put the

```
Table[...]
{

}
```

Object declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not?  I *would* recommend that you encapsulate such code in an DAL of some sort and call the API of you DAL instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include the Linq to SQL classes in the project, and then you just have to make sure you reference the namespace, if it is any different.  Worst case, you can put all the Linq to SQL stuff in a separate DLL project, and then link that project and reference the namespace.